# Proper way of doing Progress Bars C#

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I have a big project (30ish developed classes) and I want to make a loading bar for it. I have  a current progress and total progress bars. I also have to roughly describe what is happening during the current process.

The way that I did it is manually (haters gonna hate) go through the most greedy process and did estimations of how long it is gonna take (when it is a for loop, just do step ups each iteration).

I read that Background_Worker would be much more smoother, but as I read on, it appeared to me  that I still do have to go to every chunk of code and say that I want to increment the progress bar (The idea that I have to do it do describe the process made sense to me).

So my question was: is there a way to sort of encapsulate your method in a "block", which would automatically allocate the progress bar times? Or is there a more efficient way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: If you're running .NET 4.5, you might want to take a look at [`IProgress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298.aspx) and [`Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692.aspx). The visual part of the 'increment' depends on the application type - you could bind a value to a progress bar in WPF.

Comment: I'm running 4.0, and I still don't know what you mean.

Comment: Unfortunately we have very little idea of what your current code does. Are you doing all of this on the UI thread? If so, I'm surprised it's working at all...

Comment: You can fake a progress bar pretty easily.  Just set your approximate end time and have a timer progress the bar steadily.  Then you don't have to worry about actual progress at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to put your main processing in a different thread to NOT overload your GUI so it doesn't freeze up (user frustration) and then do your progress bar in the GUI thread (or make another thread for the bar, too). All depends on the preference.

But NEVER!! Freeze up the UI. The users just think it is dead and try to force close it.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to sort of encapsulate your method in a "block", which
>   would automatically allocate the progress bar times?

- No, progress bar is for showing a *progress*, so you have to set the *start*, *end* and *current state* values form outside (from the caller), because only caller knows what is it going to execute and have, potentially, control over it.
- Yes, it is possible, if you visualize infinit bar, that does not provide to a user some *quantitative information* about action executing, but informs to him, that *something is going on*. You also can provide some text description, that changes based on current action, so user can see that "something is going on there".

There is nothing worse from UX point of view, then leaving user uniformed, confused in front of the UI that is doing something, which is not clear.

So the both approaches are good, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a background worker with the progress bar.  Use a global variable to store the progress.

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public int Progress { set; get; }

   public void Method1() 
   {
      ...
      Progress++; 
   }

   public void Method2() 
   {
      ...
      Progress++; 
   }

   ...
}
```

As each method is called, increment the progress and call the background worker to report progress.

I know there are better solutions to this but this is just an idea.